# Using buttons to configure voice channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a lfg(looking-for-group) system when someone makes an lfg a embed with buttons is sent to the vc text chat. Everything is sent properly but the buttons don't work.

code snippet:

```py
class VCView(ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        



    @ui.button(label="Lock", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def lock_vc(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction:discord.Interaction):
        voice_channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
        canned = discord.Embed(description="Voice channel locked.",color=discord.Color.random())
        await voice_channel.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, connect=False)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=canned)
```

anytime i click on a button it returns the error:

```
2024-02-07 11:53:04 ERROR    discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view <VCView timeout=180.0 children=13> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.primary: 1> url=None disabled=False label='Lock' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\trace\Desktop\MU LFG\lfg bot\lfg.py", line 423, in lock_vc
    voice_channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'user'
```

another question how would i set permissions for the vc owner to delete it, move members, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i see the mistake i made, i put `buttion:discord.Button` before `interaction:discord.Interaction` which caused the error.